# Returning object as null returns what?

Tags: c++

I have a class and a function that returns an object of that class, if i return NULL what exactly gets returned?

Example:

```
class someclass {
    int a;
    int b;
    someclass::someclass(int a, int b) {
        this->a = a; this->b = b;
    }
};

someclass functionname() {
    return NULL;
}

someclass foo = functionname();
```

Since I dont have a default constructor for the class what gets returned? Is it an actual usable object? Or just gibberish? Why cant I check like this?

```
if (foo == NULL) {
    something
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Show us something that does, and we'll be able to tell you what happens in the code.

Comment: Your function will not compile as written. You would only be able to return NULL if you were returning a pointer to your class or if you had a constructor (not tagged as explicit) that took a single int (doing this will generate a warning as it is generally done by mistake).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is no actual null (however there is `nullptr` since new versions).
This means that NULL is defined like that:

```
#define NULL 0
```

So that it has the same qualities as 0, number variable, has. That's why you can't set your class to 0.

Comment: This is true if there is no non-explicit constructor taking an `int` like in his broken example.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler won't accept this code. `C++` unlike `Java` and `C#` does not treat class instances as pointers (or references). So, for this return it will try to create new instance of `someclass` with the code `someclass(NULL)`. Since you have no appropriate constructor, an error will occur.

If you want to have some "absent" values for the class, either program it inside class (for example, as boolean flag) or use pointers, for example:

```
someclass* functionname() {

    if( ??? ) { 
        return new someclass(2,3);
    }
    else {
       return NULL;
    }
}
```

remember that `C++` does not have grabage collector, so you will need to delete `new`ed object yourself when not needed.

```
someclass *a;
a = functionname();
...
delete a;
```

forgetting this is most annoying error in `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

The example is more of a situational description than something that should actually compile hence i didn't bother verifying it since it has nothing to do with the answer anyway and i doubt anybody would be interested in sifting through 100 lines of me defining a class and a function.

Anyway the answer is that if the class has any constructors that take 1 variable (optionally or otherwise) it will use that constructor and initialize the object with 0 in the first variable it can fit into